# How to print get request from instagram API?

Tags: python, get, instagram, instagram-api

Im trying to crawl some images using the instagram API, however I keep on getting the following error:

```
{'meta': {'error_type': 'OAuthParameterException', 'error_message': 'Missing client_id or access_token URL parameter.', 'code': 400}}

AttributeError: module 'urllib3.response' has no attribute 'content'
```

Here is my code in python:

```
    import requests
    url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=51&lng=0.098&distance=1000'
    json = requests.get(url).json()

    print (response.content)
```

Comment: Are you including a `client_id or access_token URL parameter`?

Comment: Yeah , no worries its sorted but the content error still comes up

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform the api query in a OAuth2 context.
You can check it in [apigee console](https://apigee.com/console/instagram)

If you need to fetch data programatically, use [python-instagram](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram) lib setting the mandatory data (access_token)

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
api = InstagramAPI(access_token = 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN')
#tested arguments
q=None
count=100
lat=51
lng=0.098 
min_timestamp, max_timestamp =None,None
distance=1000
result = api.media_search(q,count,lat,lng,min_timestamp,max_timestamp,distance)
```

Comment: Does q stand for Query , if so how do i specify it?

Comment: I've copied the endpoint from python-instagram github page. But in instagram api's page https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/ doesn't appear at all. Try the call without q

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much, but one more thing how do i print the result of?

Comment: you can call dir() method on a media instance to see what attrs and methods you can invoke. Furthermore, you can check the api page. The magic that converts api-json response to Media object is in models.object_from_dictionary() https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/master/instagram/models.py